# Testing controller method with OCMock and Core Data

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data, ocmock

I am just grasping the concepts of TDD and mocking, and am running into an issue in terms of how to properly.  I have a sheet that drops down and lets a user create a new core data object and save it to the data store.  I am not sure if I am taking the best approach to testing it.

```
- (IBAction)add:(id)sender 
{  
  NSString *itemName = [self.itemNameTextField stringValue];
  SGItem *newItem = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:kItemEntityName inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];
  newItem.name = itemName;

  NSError *error = nil;
  BOOL canSaveNewItem = [[self managedObjectContext] save:&error];
  if (!canSaveNewItem) 
  {
    [NSApp presentError:error]; 
  }

  [self clearFormFields];  // Private method that clears text fields, disables buttons
  [NSApp endSheet:[self window] returnCode:NSOKButton];
}
```

I'm trying to write two test methods to test this: one that tests the scenario where the managed object can't save and one where it successfully saves.

```
@interface SGAddItemWindowControllerTests : SGTestCase 
{
@private
  SGAddItemWindowController *addItemWindowController;
  id mockApp;
  id mockNameField;
}

- (void)setUp 
{
  mockNameField = [OCMockObject mockForClass:[NSTextField class]];
  mockApp = [OCMockObject mockForClass:[NSApplication class]];

  addItemWindowController = [[BLAddItemWindowController alloc] init];  
  [addItemWindowController setValue:mockNameField forKey:@"itemNameTextField"];
}

- (void)testAddingNewItemFromSheetFailed
{
  // Setup
  NSString *fakeName = @"";
  [[[mockNameField expect] andReturn:fakeName] stringValue];
  [[mockApp expect] presentError:[OCMArg any]];

  // Execute
  [addItemWindowController add:nil];

  // Verify
  [mockApp verify];
}

- (void)testAddingNewItemFromSheetSucceeds
{
  // Setup
  NSString *fakeName = @"Item Name";
  [[[mockNameField expect] andReturn:fakeName] stringValue];
  [[mockApp expect] endSheet:[OCMArg any] returnCode:NSOKButton];

  // Execute
  [addItemWindowController add:nil];

  // Verify
  [mockApp verify];
  [mockNameField verify];
}

@end
```

Here are the issues I know I have, but am not sure how to work out:

1. I am not sure how to handle dealing with the managed object context in terms of the test.   Should I bring up the entire core data stack or just create a mock of `NSManagedObjectContext`?
2. The idea of just setting the text field values as the way to trigger the if statement seems wrong.  Ideally I think I should stub out the `save:` method and return YES or NO, but given question 1 I'm not sure about the Core Data aspects of it all.

I think I'm on the right track, but I could use a second opinion on how to tackle my issues  and set me on the right path for testing the code snippet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Justin,

What I do for question #1 is to create an actual NSManagedObjectContext but create an im-memory persistence store.  Nothing hits the disk and I test the CoreData version of the truth.

I have a MWCoreDataTest class (extends in my case GTMTestCase) that builds the moc and initializes the persistence store

```
    - (NSManagedObjectContext *) managedObjectContext {

    if (managedObjectContext != nil) {
        return managedObjectContext;
    }

    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
    if (coordinator != nil) {
        managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
        [managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator: coordinator];
    }

    return managedObjectContext;
}



- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator*)persistentStoreCoordinator;
{
    if (persistentStoreCoordinator) return persistentStoreCoordinator;
    NSError* error = nil;
    NSManagedObjectModel *mom = [self managedObjectModel];
    persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc]
                                  initWithManagedObjectModel:mom];


    if (![persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSInMemoryStoreType
                                                  configuration:nil
                                                            URL:nil
                                                        options:nil
                                                          error:&error]) {
        [[NSApplication sharedApplication] presentError:error];
        return nil;
    }
    return persistentStoreCoordinator;
}
```

WRT #2, I think that's ok - if you plan on testing more than one behavior in the class, move the

```
[addItemWindowController setValue:mockNameField forKey:@"itemNameTextField"];
```

to the testAdding.. method

If you solve #1, then you could just set the itemNameText field to nil and your save validation would trigger.

WRT #3, I would validate that building a mock on NSApp === building a mock on NSApplication

Answer (score 0):

What is that you want to test? Do you want to test that Core Data does the saving or not? Or, do you want to test that your application responds correctly to the result of the call to CoreData?

Either way I think you should extract a method that performs the saving along the lines of:

```
-(BOOL)saveNewItem:(NSString *)itemName error:(NSError **)error { 
    SGItem *newItem = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:kItemEntityName inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];
  newItem.name = itemName;

  NSError *error = nil;
  return[[self managedObjectContext] save:&error];
}

- (IBAction)add:(id)sender {  
  NSString *itemName = [self.itemNameTextField stringValue];
  NSError *error = nil;
  BOOL canSaveNewItem = [self saveNewItem:itemName error:&error];
  if (!canSaveNewItem) {
    [NSApp presentError:error]; 
  }

  [self clearFormFields];  // Private method that clears text fields, disables buttons
  [NSApp endSheet:[self window] returnCode:NSOKButton];
}
```

This way you can test that Core Data saving works as expected by settings up an in memory store and not have to care about the business logic. You should also be able to override or mock the result of this method for testing the business logic.

I would perhaps even move all the Core Data stuff to a separate class that would encapsulate  the interaction for easier mocking.